# how to restore postgreSQL 8.3 DB after unistall

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-8.3

I have unfortunately broken my old machine with postgres 8.3 on debian 6.0, I found a directory backup of postgresql database files, and i try to copy them on the new machine with a new version of postgres 9.1, but postgres on start fail with error:

```
[FAIL with server 2022-05-05 14:22:42 GMT DETAIL: The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 8.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.1.21. ... failed! failed!
```

I found several guides explaining how to upgrade from an older version to a newer one, but these only work if you have the old version installed and working, in my case I can't install the old one anymore as postgresql 8.3 is no longer supported. How can I recover the old db and data?

Update..., this all command that I runnig:

```
#initialize db
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D pgdata
#copy original files
cp -r /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/* pgdata/
#start server
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D ./pgdata -l logfile start
>server starting
#check log
tail logfile
>   FATAL:  database "DB2" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB0" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB1" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB2" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB0" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB1" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB2" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB0" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB1" does not exist
>   FATAL:  database "DB2" does not exist

/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql
psql: FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_dumpall > db.out
>   pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  database "template1" does not exist
```

@Laurenz Albe

Comment: 9.1 is far from being "a new version". Its end-of-life was about 6 years ago. To revive a 8.3 data directory you will have to install 8.3. As it isn't supported any more, you will have to compile it from source which can still be downloaded: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v8.3.23/

Comment: I compiled and installed postgresql 8.3.23, the db was initialized and works correctly, so I stopped it and copied my old files from the path: "8.3/main/base" in "pgdata/base" without overwriting the folders 1, 11510, 11511. I restarted the db correctly, but I still can't see my old db. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install 8.3, probably from source, on a machine with the same architecture. Then copy the *complete* data directory to that machine and start the server on it.

Now `pg_dumpall` the cluster and restore it to PostgreSQL v14.

You should not run `initdb` at all. Instead,

```sh
cp -r /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main pgdata
```

If the data directory was complete, you should be able to start the server after that.

Comment: I copied all, but now the service works but it doesn't see any db, pg_dumpall says: 

could not connect to database "template1": could not connect to server: No such file or directory. 

then i tried with pg_upgrade, but:
Old and new pg_controldata date/time storage types do not match.

You will need to rebuild the new server with configure
--disable-integer-datetimes or get server binaries built
with those options.

I recompiled using this option, but nothing has changed, I checked the help and in fact the compiler haven't  --disable-integer-datetimes. What else can I try?

Comment: Start the server and run `pg_dumpall`. If you have trouble doing that, please edit the question and post the exact commands you used and the response.

Comment: I updated the question with exact commands as you want, do you find any errors?